# Maven 3.0.4 - execute annotation processors after compile

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, apt

I would like to run the following basic procedure within my Maven 3.0.4 project.  I have all the basics in place and haven't had any issues but am running into problems on step #3.  For some reason the basic solution is eluding me, since it seems like something that should be very obvious.

1. Run a basic clean/install (without annotation processing)
2. Request that a site build be run
3. Before the site build kicks off, **run annotation processing on the compiled classes using an annotation processor class that was compiled in the initial steps**

I tried setting up the annotation processing goal as follows:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>process</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>process</goal>
      </goals>
      <phase>pre-site</phase>
      <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/generated-documentation</outputDirectory>
        <processors>
          <processor>com.mydomain.MyFancyAnnotationProcessor</processor>
        </processors>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

For some reason this doesn't seem to be working.
I feel like I'm doing something very, very silly that is preventing it from working.

I am using the [Maven Annotation Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-annotation-plugin/) instead of the basic, [Mojo Apt Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/apt-maven-plugin/).  I don't mind switching if someone has a working solution with that one.  I tried both without any immediate signs of success.  Again, it feels like it's just something obvious that I'm overlooking.

**Error received:**

```
[INFO] diagnostic error: Annotation processor 'com.mydomain.MyFancyAnnotationProcessor' not found
[ERROR] error on execute: error during compilation
```

Comment: what _specifically_ isn't working?  it isn't running?  it's generating an error?  you get the wrong output...?

Comment: apologies - I updated the entry with the error at the bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be that the plugin is not including the current project itself in its classpath.  The best solution would be to separate the annotation processor into its own (sub-)module if possible.  If you can't do that, you may be able to just add this project itself as a dependency of the plugin (using a `<dependencies>` section under the plugin node).

As a diagnostic note, you can run maven with the '-X' argument to see detailed info about the build.  This should show you exactly what is on the classpath when the plugin is executed.